# How to make a fo:block not affect page layout?

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm using an empty `fo:block` with an id at the end of a page sequence and referencing it in the table of contents to get the ending page number, but I just had an instance where the text of the page was at the very bottom and adding the empty `fo:block` caused a blank page to be added after the text.

How can I insert an empty `fo:block` with an id and not have it affect the pagination? I would think adding the attribute `visibility='collapse'` would work, but the documentation I was looking at said:

> collapse: If used on elements other than rows or columns, "collapse" **has the same meaning as "hidden"**.
>
> hidden: The generated box is invisible (fully transparent), but **still
>   affects layout**.

How can I tell the last `fo:block` to not affect the page layout? Here is the FO output I currently have:

```
          ...
        </fo:table-and-caption>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block id="123456" />
    </fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
...
```

Comment: Set keep with previous on the block and set font size ro 0pt and line-height to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the end page number of fo:page-sequence, use fo:page-number-citation-last in toc instead of generating dummy fo:block.

6.6.12 fo:page-number-citation-last

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-number-citation-last

Here is sample FO snippet:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" font-size="10pt" id="page-seq-001">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
      <fo:block><fo:page-number/></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-size="2em">TOC</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            Last page 
            <fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" leader-pattern="dots"/>
            <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="page-seq-001"/>
        </fo:block>
        ...
```

This will be formatted as follows:

[image]